# Android Email or SMS ALerts

Tags: android

How could I best send a message using the Android from an external email address to the user's email address or SMS?

For example, when the phone senses acceleration, it sends a message from youdroppedme@gmail.com to the user's gmail account.

I would prefer to use the core API, if possible. I am also considering using a web server as a go between. What is the most elegant solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How about this answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-ap/2033124#2033124)  It sends email in android using the JavaMail API using Gmail authentication.

Comment: Looks good- but for some reason it isn't working for me. I think I must be doing something wrong on my end: it compiles fine, and when I look at the debugger it doesn't catch an exception when sending the mail, but not emails appear in my inbox. Ideas?

Comment: @Geekgirl I haven't actually used it.  Is it setup using the correct smtp server information or ports?  Is it showing up in your spam box?